# How to prove $\int_{B(0,r)}|\log |x||dx\le cr^2|\log r|$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can we prove $\int_{B(0,r)}|\log |x||dx\le cr^2|\log r|,r\to 0$? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\log|x|$ and you're working in ${\mathbb R}^2$, switch to polar coordinates and just do the integral.

Comment: How can this be true? If $r=1$, the upper bound is zero, but the integral is clearly not.

Comment: It still cannot be true. The limit as $r \to 1$ of the right hand side is still zero, but the left hand side is increasing as a function of $r$ and is non-zero.

Comment: Is this the final question?

Comment: Yes, thank @copper.hat.

Comment: Thank @Zarrax for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r<1$:
$$\int |\log |x||dx = r(1 - \log r) = r(|\log r|+1)$$
Now to find $c$, use the function:
$$f(r) = c r |\log r|-|\log r|$$
Now for suitable $c$, $f(r) \ge 1$, so: 
$$\int |\log |x||dx = r(|\log r|+1) \le cr^2 |\log r|$$
Now for all $r$ in the open interval $(0,1)$ there exists such a $c$, but this is of course a function of $r$.

Comment: How can you conclude $r(|\log r|+1) \le cr^2 |\log r|$? Divide across by $r$ and let $r \uparrow 1$, then you get $1 \le 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat - for large enough $c$, it works out, but as I stated only in the open interval.

Comment: If $c$ is a function of $r$, then the bound is rather meaningless. All it states is that $r^2 |\log r| \neq 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat - Never claimed it meant anything, I just tried to show that $c$ cannot be constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nbubis. I like your answer. Also thank copper.hat comments.